# Secure random unique number in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a loop that adds numbers in groups of a certain number which can be inputted by the user.

```
no_reps = @trial.number_of_repetitions
```

I'm looking to input a random number between one and the `no_reps` variable in groups of `no_reps` variable.

Current the `r.treatment_index = SecureRandom.random_number(1..no_reps)` isn't putting in unique numbers. The values match the range, but aren't unique per `in_groups_of`.

```
@trial.repetitions.in_groups_of(no_reps).each_with_index do |a, i|
  a.each do |r|
   r.repetition_index = i + 1
   r.treatment_index = SecureRandom.random_number(1..no_reps)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to `#shuffle` prepopulated array:

```
@trial.repetitions.in_groups_of(no_reps).each_with_index do |a, i|
  treatment_indexes = (1..no_reps).to_a.shuffle
  a.each_with_index do |r, j|
   r.repetition_index = i + 1
   r.treatment_index = treatment_indexes[j]
  end
end
```

**UPD:** If you take care about speed:

```
treatment_indexes = (1..no_reps).to_a
@trial.repetitions.in_groups_of(no_reps).each_with_index do |a, i|
  treatment_indexes.shuffle!
  ...
```